# Escape apostrophe in aspx file

Tags: asp.net, javascript, xml, escaping

How do I escape apostrophes / single quotes in ASP.net XML?

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server"
    OnClientClick='confirm("How do you escape this apos'trophe?")' />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClone" runat="server" OnClick="btnClone_Click"
    OnClientClick="confirm('How do you escape this apos\'trophe?')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server"
    OnClientClick='confirm("How do you escape this apos&#39;trophe?")' />
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the confirmation box doesn't evaluate the html codes. Or does it?